# Meteor - Register multiple helpers at once

Tags: meteor, spacebars

In my Meteor app (v1.1.0.2) I have 10 global helpers:

```js
Template.registerHelper("getUser", function(id) {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({
        _id: id
    });
});

Template.registerHelper("getPublication", function(id) {
    return Publications.findOne({
        _id: id
    });
});

Template.registerHelper("getCategory", function(id) {
    return Categories.findOne(new Mongo.ObjectID(id));
});

Template.registerHelper("getAge", function(id) {
    return Ages.findOne(new Mongo.ObjectID(id));
});

Template.registerHelper("getPhoto", function(id) {
    return new FS.File(ImagesPublications.findOne({
        _id: id
    }));
});

Template.registerHelper("optionsCategories", function(id) {
    return Categories.find().map(function(element) {
        return {
            label: element.name,
            value: element._id._str
        };
    });
});

Template.registerHelper("optionsAges", function(id) {
    return Ages.find().map(function(element) {
        return {
            label: element.name,
            value: element._id._str
        };
    });
});

Template.registerHelper("allowedCategories", function(id) {
    return Categories.find().map(function(element) {
        return element._id._str;
    });
});

Template.registerHelper("allowedAges", function(id) {
    return Ages.find().map(function(element) {
        return element._id._str;
    });
});

Template.registerHelper("prettifyDate", function(date) {
    return moment(date).format('L HH:mm:ss');
});
```

I was trying to compact all this in a single function call using an object:

```js
Template.registerHelper({
    getUser: function(id) {
        return Meteor.users.findOne({
            _id: id
        });
    },
    getPublication: function(id) {
        return Publications.findOne({
            _id: id
        });
    },
    getCategory: function(id) {
        return Categories.findOne(new Mongo.ObjectID(id));
    },
    getAge: function(id) {
        return Ages.findOne(new Mongo.ObjectID(id));
    },
    getPhoto: function(id) {
        return new FS.File(ImagesPublications.findOne({
            _id: id
        }));
    },
    optionsCategories: function(id) {
        return Categories.find().map(function(element) {
            return {
                label: element.name,
                value: element._id._str
            };
        });
    },
    optionsAges: function(id) {
        return Ages.find().map(function(element) {
            return {
                label: element.name,
                value: element._id._str
            };
        });
    },
    allowedCategories: function(id) {
        return Categories.find().map(function(element) {
            return element._id._str;
        });
    },
    allowedAges: function(id) {
        return Ages.find().map(function(element) {
            return element._id._str;
        });
    },
    prettifyDate: function(date) {
        return moment(date).format('L HH:mm:ss');
    }
});
```

I tried the above without success, so I was wondering if I could do something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just put your helpers in a key / value dictionary like this :

```
var helpers = {
  getAge: function(id) {
    return Ages.findOne(new Mongo.ObjectID(id));
  }
};
```

Then use a loop to iterate over each pair and register the helper inside.

```
_.each(helpers, function(value, key){
  Template.registerHelper(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Damn, you are right. I don't know why I didn't think that, it's so obvious. I fell like an idiot... Thanks!